# jspdf Devnagari(Nepalese/ Hindi) Font

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf

I want to generate pdf in Devanagari(Nepalese/ Hindi) font using jspdf. It is working but some words are not displaying properly. 
For Example:
 हाम्रो: हाम् रो,
 प्रकार: प् रकार

```
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.addFileToVFS('akchyar-unicode.ttf', nepali)  
doc.addFont('akchyar-unicode.ttf', 'custom', 'normal');

doc.setFont('custom');
doc.text(60, 20, 'हाम्रो प्रकार');
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this by any chance?