# Dompdf problem with displaying Nepali character

Tags: laravel, pdf, unicode, utf-8, dompdf

I am using Dompdf to create a pdf for my Nepali content. I have written following code in my controller:

```
public function generatePDF(Request $request){
  $data = $this->news->where('slug', $request->slug)->first();
  $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <title>". $data->title ."</title>
      <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: preeti;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('{{ asset('/frontend/fonts/preeti.ttf') }}') format('truetype');
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body style='font-family: preeti;'>
      <img src='".$data->image ."' style='width: 100%; height: auto'>
      ". $data->description ."
  </body>
  </html>";
  $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
  $pdf = PDF::setOptions(['dpi' => 150, 'defaultFont' => 'preeti']);
  $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);      
  return $pdf->download('sample.pdf');
}
```

But this gives ???? as an output of the Nepali content inside the canvas. However, `<title>". $data->title ."</title>` displays right character. What can I do to fix this?

As you can see I have kept `UTF-8` in my `meta` also have included CSS for the font but it does not seem to work. I have also included `mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');` but it made no change. Does anyone has fixed this kind of issue?

The output of `$data->description` is

```
<p>अहिले कार्यान्वयनको चरणमा रहेको नेपालको संघीय प्रणालीमा एकभन्दा बढी संसद् र 

कार्यपालिकाहरू छन् । तर, पनि संघीय प्रणालीबारे हामीकहाँ एक प्रकारको नका ▶
<p>स्थानीय संरचना भनेको तपाईं, हामी सबैले आ&ndash;आफ्नै घरदैलोमा भेट्ने सरकार हो । स्थानीय तह पुनर्संंरचना गर्दा संख्या घटाउनुलाई नै बहादुरी ठानियो । ७५३ वटा स् ▶
<p>स्थानीय तहलाई अहिले जति अधिकार दिइएको छ, त्यो पनि धान्न सक्ने ल्याकत तिनमा देखिंदैन । संविधानले दिएका धेरै अधिकार स्थानीय तहमा कार्यान्वयन भइरहेका छैनन् । ति ▶
<p>संविधानमा पनि केही त्रुटिहरू छन् । संविधान बनाउँदा स्थानीय तहलाई व्यवस्था गरिएका अधिकारहरूबारे आवश्यक गृहकार्य भएन, सोचिएन । क्षमता विनाको भारी बोकाउन खोज्दा ▶
<p><strong>संघीयताः कतिपय अमिल्दा पक्ष</strong><br />संविधानको कार्यान्वयन हुँदै जाँदा प्रदेशहरू निरन्तर असान्दर्भिक र भूमिकाहीन देखिंदै गएका छन् । अहिले संविधा ▶
<p>जत्रो आकारमा ७५३ वटा स्थानीय तह रचना गरिएको छ र त्यसले जुन प्रकारको राजनीतिक र प्रशासनिक संरचनाको माग गर्छ; त्यो कतै प्रदेशकै विकल्प सोचेर गरिएको त होइन भन्न ▶
<p>हुन पनि, काठमाडौंमा बस्ने धेरैजसोलाई संघीयता मन परेको छैन । कार्यकारी जिम्मेवारी लिएको हुनाले यसको ठूलो अपजस चाहिं सत्तारूढ दललाई नै जान्छ । प्रधानमन्त्रीलाई ▶
<p>तर प्रदेशलाई कमजोर पार्दा अन्ततः संविधानको कार्यान्वयन कमजोर हुन्छ । किनभने, संघीय संरचनाको एउटा अङ्ग कमजोर भएपछि त्यसको असर अरू अङ्गमा स्वतः पर्छ र संविधान  ▶
<p>प्रदेशको कुरा गर्दा म अहिले तीनवटा मह&OElig;वपूर्ण पक्ष देख्छु । पहिलो, प्रदेशहरूले आफ्नो विशिष्ट उपस्थिति देखाउन सकिरहेका छैनन् । प्रदेश सभा छ, त्यसका सदस्य ▶
<p>संविधानको अनुसूचीको व्यवस्था अनुसार संघ, प्रदेश र स्थानीय तहको अधिकार छुट्याउन मुख्यसचिवको कार्यदलले लामो कार्यसूची तयार पारेको थियो । पछि त्यसैको आधारमा &ls ▶
<p><strong>परिणामतः</strong> सबै कुरामा प्रदेशहरूले सिंहदरबारकै सिको गर्न थाले । सिंहदरबारको योजना आयोगको साटो प्रदेशमा नीति आयोगहरू बने । सिंहदरबारकै जस्ता अरू ▶
<p>केन्द्र या काठमाडौंलाई नक्कल गरेका नमूना ठाउँठाउँमा भेट्न सकिन्छ । जस्तो, गण्डकी प्रदेशमा &lsquo;मुख्यमन्त्री नमूना कृषि कार्यक्रम&rsquo; छ । लुम्ले, जहाँ हि ▶
<p><strong>केन्द्रको प्रतिछायाँका रूपमा प्रदेश</strong><br />संघ र ६ वटा प्रदेश सभामा नेकपाको बहुमत छ । त्यसैले त्यहाँको राजनीति र नीति निर्माणमा ऊ हावी हुने कु ▶
<p>संघीयता कार्यान्वयनको सन्दर्भमा प्रदेश&ndash;२ को भिन्न र सार्थक भूमिका किन पनि अपेक्षित थियो भने त्यो प्रदेश सिंहदरबारमा बस्नेहरू भन्दा फरक दलको नेतृत्वमा छ ▶
<p>प्रदेशहरूले कसरी अगाडि जान सकिन्छ भन्ने चिन्तन गरेकै देखिएन । संविधान कार्यान्वयन भएको चार वर्ष बितिसक्दा पनि प्रदेशहरूले आफ्नो अस्तित्व नागरिकसामु पु&yen;या ▶
<p><strong>प्रदेशका लागि &lsquo;फूटनोट&rsquo;</strong><br />हाम्रा यावत् समस्या र विसङ्गतिका निम्ति संविधानलाई दोष दिएर मात्र पुग्दैन । सबैभन्दा ठूलो खाँचो सकार ▶
<p>अहिले प्रदेशहरू बढी नै केन्द्रीय सत्तामुखी देखिएका छन् । सात वटै प्रदेशबाट एकैचोटि भिन्न व्यवहारको अपेक्षा गर्न नसकिएला तर, एक&divide;दुई वटाले यसप्रकारको भू ▶
<p>अहिले सबै प्रदेशले कर्मचारीको कुरा उठाउँछन् । संविधानले प्रदेशहरूलाई लोकसेवा आयोग बनाउन अधिकार दिएको छ । त्यसअनुरूप सबै प्रदेशले लोकसेवा आयोग बनाएका पनि छन्  ▶
<p>प्रदेशले बनाएका कानून भोलि संघीय कानूनसित बाझे भने त्यो त्यसैबेला छिनोफानो हुने कुरा हो । तर, अहिले संघीय कानून नै नबनेका बेला त्यससँग बाझिने भन्ने कुरा कहाँ ▶
<p>त्यस्तै; विकासको क्षेत्रमा पनि प्रदेशले एउटा, दुइटा नमूना कार्यक्रम सञ्चालन गर्न सक्थे । जस्तो&mdash; प्रदेश&ndash;२ मा &lsquo;बेटी पढाओ, बेटी बचाओ&rsquo; मु ▶
<p>संविधानले प्रदेशहरूलाई प्रदेश तहका योजना बनाएर कार्यान्वयन गर्न छूट दिएको छ । प्रदेश तहको योजना भनेको के हो ? त्यसको पहिचान गर्न सकिन्थ्यो । मानौं, प्रदेश तह ▶
<p>जलविद्युत्मा सम्भाव्यता भएका प्रदेशका नेतृत्व बसेर सहमतिका आधारमा कतै १०० मेगावाट, कतै २०० मेगावाट त कतै ९०० मेगावाटसम्मका जलविद्युत् आयोजना सञ्चालन गर्ने भन ▶
<p><strong>संविधान बुझ्ने सूत्र</strong><br />अहिले मिडिया, अझ &lsquo;सोसल मिडिया&rsquo; मा संघीयता &lsquo;चल्दैन&rsquo; भन्ने कुरा बारम्बार आइरहन्छ । जबकि, संव ▶
<p>यस्तो ऐतिहासिक पृष्ठभूमिमा आमनागरिकमा अस्थिर सोचाइ आउनु त्यति अव्यावहारिक र अस्वाभाविक होइन । हाम्रोमा सधैं अस्थिरताको जुन किसिमको पृष्ठभूमि रह्यो त्यसले पनि ▶
<p>हामीमा संविधानप्रतिको चेतना, संविधानप्रतिको बुझाइको अभाव छ । यो असाध्य मह&OElig;वपूर्ण पक्ष हो । संविधान कार्यान्वयनको शुरूआती चरणमा यस्तो चेतना सत्तारूढ दल  ▶
<p>संविधान कार्यान्वयनले अहिले एउटा बाटो लिंदैछ । घोषणा गर्दा जति चुनौती थिए तिनलाई पार गरेर संविधान अगाडि बढेको छ । सत्ता सञ्चालन गर्ने दलको कार्यशैलीले भन्दा  ▶
<p><em><strong>राजनीतिशास्त्री खनालसँगको वार्तामा आधारित</strong></em></p>
```

Comment: try this answer, tries for some other language using dompdf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45714545/dompdf-package-other-languages-support-in-laravel

Comment: @bhucho None of the answers from your shared link worked. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: can you show inside data->description is the other language content, can you edit to show some dummy text which looks like this other language

Comment: @bhucho I have added the output of `$data->description`

Comment: hello got struck in some deadlines, I tried by using your code and managed to solved it for some other english font but is not working for this font, I have raised an issue in dompdf see here https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2209. This issue also contains the steps I followed so you might see it as well

Comment: There are other ways without using dompdf if you are interested in it you can use that or wait for someone to give reply to the above issue

Comment: @bhucho Thank you for making time to reply. If other methods can solve my issue then I am happy to use them. Have you tested with any other method and that has worked too?

Comment: hello, I have tried with TCPDF, its working will attach the steps in answer

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane did you find a solution to this? what did you do to solve this? please let me know hai. kasto support nabhako tait yo library ma.

Comment: @SauravBajracharya No. There was nothing I could do. I tried everything but none of the solutions worked. I shifted to generating word file instead of pdf.

Comment: Hi @AlishaLamichhane I was able to make kantipur and devnagari font work using load_fonts.php file from the utils repo of DOMPDF. but it still works only with बकमन keyboard

Comment: @SauravBajracharya Thank you for the update. You are very welcome to add your answer here if you succeed.

Answer (score 2):

As Mentioned in the comments, `dompdf/domPDF` after following the steps as mentioned above does not give the desired results, see [this](http://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2209),

I suggest the use of TCPDF.  [elibyy / tcpdf-laravel](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel) provides a way to add tcpdf in laravel.

Install it using 
`composer require elibyy/tcpdf-laravel`.

Add this to your `provider` in `config/app.php` 

`Elibyy\TCPDF\ServiceProvider::class,`

Then In your controller add the lines

```
use Elibyy\TCPDF\Facades\TCPDF;

public function generatePDF(){
        $data = new \stdClass(); //can be your model, I have just used empty object
        $public_path = public_path();
        $data->title = "<p>प्रणालीबारे हामीकहाँ एक</p>";
        $data->description =  "<p>अहिले कार्यान्वयनको चरणमा रहेको नेपालको संघीय प्रणालीमा एकभन्दा बढी संसद् र 

        कार्यपालिकाहरू छन् । तर, पनि संघीय प्रणालीबारे हामीकहाँ एक प्रकारको नका ▶
        <p>स्थानीय संरचना भनेको तपाईं, हामी सबैले आ&ndash;आफ्नै घरदैलोमा भेट्ने सरकार हो । स्थानीय तह पुनर्संंरचना गर्दा संख्या घटाउनुलाई नै बहादुरी ठानियो । ७५३ वटा स् ▶
        <p>स्थानीय तहलाई अहिले जति अधिकार दिइएको छ, त्यो पनि धान्न सक्ने ल्याकत तिनमा देखिंदैन । संविधानले दिएका धेरै अधिकार स्थानीय तहमा कार्यान्वयन भइरहेका छैनन् । ति ▶
        <p>संविधानमा पनि केही त्रुटिहरू छन् । संविधान बनाउँदा स्थानीय तहलाई व्यवस्था गरिएका अधिकारहरूबारे आवश्यक गृहकार्य भएन, सोचिएन । क्षमता विनाको भारी बोकाउन खोज्दा ▶
        <p><strong>संघीयताः कतिपय अमिल्दा पक्ष</strong><br />संविधानको कार्यान्वयन हुँदै जाँदा प्रदेशहरू निरन्तर असान्दर्भिक र भूमिकाहीन देखिंदै गएका छन् । अहिले संविधा ▶
        <p>जत्रो आकारमा ७५३ वटा स्थानीय तह रचना गरिएको छ र त्यसले जुन प्रकारको राजनीतिक र प्रशासनिक संरचनाको माग गर्छ; त्यो कतै प्रदेशकै विकल्प सोचेर गरिएको त होइन भन्न ▶
        <p>हुन पनि, काठमाडौंमा बस्ने धेरैजसोलाई संघीयता मन परेको छैन । कार्यकारी जिम्मेवारी लिएको हुनाले यसको ठूलो अपजस चाहिं सत्तारूढ दललाई नै जान्छ । प्रधानमन्त्रीलाई ▶
        <p>तर प्रदेशलाई कमजोर पार्दा अन्ततः संविधानको कार्यान्वयन कमजोर हुन्छ । किनभने, संघीय संरचनाको एउटा अङ्ग कमजोर भएपछि त्यसको असर अरू अङ्गमा स्वतः पर्छ र संविधान  ▶
        <p>प्रदेशको कुरा गर्दा म अहिले तीनवटा मह&OElig;वपूर्ण पक्ष देख्छु । पहिलो, प्रदेशहरूले आफ्नो विशिष्ट उपस्थिति देखाउन सकिरहेका छैनन् । प्रदेश सभा छ, त्यसका सदस्य ▶
        <p>संविधानको अनुसूचीको व्यवस्था अनुसार संघ, प्रदेश र स्थानीय तहको अधिकार छुट्याउन मुख्यसचिवको कार्यदलले लामो कार्यसूची तयार पारेको थियो । पछि त्यसैको आधारमा &ls ▶
        <p><strong>परिणामतः</strong> सबै कुरामा प्रदेशहरूले सिंहदरबारकै सिको गर्न थाले । सिंहदरबारको योजना आयोगको साटो प्रदेशमा नीति आयोगहरू बने । सिंहदरबारकै जस्ता अरू ▶
        <p>केन्द्र या काठमाडौंलाई नक्कल गरेका नमूना ठाउँठाउँमा भेट्न सकिन्छ । जस्तो, गण्डकी प्रदेशमा &lsquo;मुख्यमन्त्री नमूना कृषि कार्यक्रम&rsquo; छ । लुम्ले, जहाँ हि ▶
        <p><strong>केन्द्रको प्रतिछायाँका रूपमा प्रदेश</strong><br />संघ र ६ वटा प्रदेश सभामा नेकपाको बहुमत छ । त्यसैले त्यहाँको राजनीति र नीति निर्माणमा ऊ हावी हुने कु ▶
        <p>संघीयता कार्यान्वयनको सन्दर्भमा प्रदेश&ndash;२ को भिन्न र सार्थक भूमिका किन पनि अपेक्षित थियो भने त्यो प्रदेश सिंहदरबारमा बस्नेहरू भन्दा फरक दलको नेतृत्वमा छ ▶
        <p>प्रदेशहरूले कसरी अगाडि जान सकिन्छ भन्ने चिन्तन गरेकै देखिएन । संविधान कार्यान्वयन भएको चार वर्ष बितिसक्दा पनि प्रदेशहरूले आफ्नो अस्तित्व नागरिकसामु पु&yen;या ▶
        <p><strong>प्रदेशका लागि &lsquo;फूटनोट&rsquo;</strong><br />हाम्रा यावत् समस्या र विसङ्गतिका निम्ति संविधानलाई दोष दिएर मात्र पुग्दैन । सबैभन्दा ठूलो खाँचो सकार ▶
        <p>अहिले प्रदेशहरू बढी नै केन्द्रीय सत्तामुखी देखिएका छन् । सात वटै प्रदेशबाट एकैचोटि भिन्न व्यवहारको अपेक्षा गर्न नसकिएला तर, एक&divide;दुई वटाले यसप्रकारको भू ▶
        <p>अहिले सबै प्रदेशले कर्मचारीको कुरा उठाउँछन् । संविधानले प्रदेशहरूलाई लोकसेवा आयोग बनाउन अधिकार दिएको छ । त्यसअनुरूप सबै प्रदेशले लोकसेवा आयोग बनाएका पनि छन्  ▶
        <p>प्रदेशले बनाएका कानून भोलि संघीय कानूनसित बाझे भने त्यो त्यसैबेला छिनोफानो हुने कुरा हो । तर, अहिले संघीय कानून नै नबनेका बेला त्यससँग बाझिने भन्ने कुरा कहाँ ▶
        <p>त्यस्तै; विकासको क्षेत्रमा पनि प्रदेशले एउटा, दुइटा नमूना कार्यक्रम सञ्चालन गर्न सक्थे । जस्तो&mdash; प्रदेश&ndash;२ मा &lsquo;बेटी पढाओ, बेटी बचाओ&rsquo; मु ▶
        <p>संविधानले प्रदेशहरूलाई प्रदेश तहका योजना बनाएर कार्यान्वयन गर्न छूट दिएको छ । प्रदेश तहको योजना भनेको के हो ? त्यसको पहिचान गर्न सकिन्थ्यो । मानौं, प्रदेश तह ▶
        <p>जलविद्युत्मा सम्भाव्यता भएका प्रदेशका नेतृत्व बसेर सहमतिका आधारमा कतै १०० मेगावाट, कतै २०० मेगावाट त कतै ९०० मेगावाटसम्मका जलविद्युत् आयोजना सञ्चालन गर्ने भन ▶
        <p><strong>संविधान बुझ्ने सूत्र</strong><br />अहिले मिडिया, अझ &lsquo;सोसल मिडिया&rsquo; मा संघीयता &lsquo;चल्दैन&rsquo; भन्ने कुरा बारम्बार आइरहन्छ । जबकि, संव ▶
        <p>यस्तो ऐतिहासिक पृष्ठभूमिमा आमनागरिकमा अस्थिर सोचाइ आउनु त्यति अव्यावहारिक र अस्वाभाविक होइन । हाम्रोमा सधैं अस्थिरताको जुन किसिमको पृष्ठभूमि रह्यो त्यसले पनि ▶
        <p>हामीमा संविधानप्रतिको चेतना, संविधानप्रतिको बुझाइको अभाव छ । यो असाध्य मह&OElig;वपूर्ण पक्ष हो । संविधान कार्यान्वयनको शुरूआती चरणमा यस्तो चेतना सत्तारूढ दल  ▶
        <p>संविधान कार्यान्वयनले अहिले एउटा बाटो लिंदैछ । घोषणा गर्दा जति चुनौती थिए तिनलाई पार गरेर संविधान अगाडि बढेको छ । सत्ता सञ्चालन गर्ने दलको कार्यशैलीले भन्दा  ▶
        <p><em><strong>राजनीतिशास्त्री खनालसँगको वार्तामा आधारित</strong></em></p> "; 
        $html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
          <meta charset='UTF-8'>
            <title>". $data->title ."</title>
            <style>
            @font-face {
              font-family: 'preeti';
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: 400;
              src:url('".$public_path."/public/PREETI.TTF' format('woff');
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body style='font-family: preeti;'>
            ". $data->description ."
        </body>
        </html>";
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
        
        
        $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
        $pdf::setFontSubSetting(true);
        $pdf::setFont('freeserif','',12);
        // $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
        $pdf::AddPage();
        $pdf::writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);
        $output = $pdf::Output('001.pdf', 'I');

        return $output;    
      }
```

Should get output like this.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for try this & give an answer here

Comment: If you notice the spelling is not correct. I tried converting the `preeti` fonts and many other Nepali fonts to TCPDF fonts but also did not get the expected output. I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: then you can use jsPDF(js only), pass $html to a blade file, then use https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF ,but still there are chances that it can fail(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153379/jspdf-devnagarinepalese-hindi-font)

Comment: normally as I saw answers, All these libraries have problem handling compound letters.Sorry,  I tried my best, here as well there are compound letters in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24440261/php-dompdf-html-to-pdf-converter-font-rendering-issue-in-v-0-6-1/24483450

Comment: there is MPDF as well, but I have never used it ever, you can try that as well

Comment: The last solution is you can create/write text in svg, then embed your svg in pdf using javascript, it will give you the exact desired output but it will only be svg inside pdf

Comment: I have tried Mpdf already. I does not give the expected. Any solution is welcome. I haven’t tried SVG so I would like to know the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm way too late for this, but for someone who will need this in future, This solution worked for me. This uses the Dompdf\Dompdf.

```
    $pdfOptions = new Options();
    $pdfOptions->setChroot(storage_path('fonts/'));
    $pdfOptions->set('fontDir', storage_path('fonts/'));
    $pdfOptions->set('fontCache', storage_path('fonts/'));
    $pdfOptions->set('defaultFont', 'Preeti');

    $pdf = new Dompdf($pdfOptions);

    $pdf->getFontMetrics()->registerFont(
        ['family' => 'Preeti', 'style' => 'normal', 'weight' => 'normal'],
        storage_path('fonts/') . 'Preeti.ttf'
    ); 

    $pdf->loadHtml(\View::make('pdf.template', compact('data'))->render());

    $pdf->render();

    $pdf->stream();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using laravel to export a table which has nepali contents tried using dompdf but nepali character were not supported later found this solution in stack and worked for me..

```
public function generatePDF()
{
    $monitors = Monitor::all();
    $test = View('pages.printables.monitor.print', compact('monitors'))->render();
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($test, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf::setFontSubSetting(true);
    $pdf::setFont('freeserif', '', 12);
    // $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);
    $pdf::AddPage();
    $pdf::writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, true);
    $output = $pdf::Output('001.pdf', 'I');

    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations in dompdf. So Nepali fonts could not be rendered properly. Don't waste your time trying different fonts in dompdf. Please use MPDF, and it's better than dompdf. You can render the Nepali font as you expected.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf

Controller Code:

```
public function download(string $id)
{   
     $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.applications.pdf');

     return $pdf->download('pdf.pdf');
}
```

Blade File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "freesans", sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
            १४ चैत, फिक्कल । पछिल्लो समय इलाममा अदुवाखेती विस्तार हुँदै गएको छ । अदुवाखेतीले यहाँका किसानको जीवनस्तरमा परिवर्तन ल्याउन थालेपछि खेती विस्तार भएको हो । किसानले व्यावसायिकरुपमा अदुवाखेती गरी मनग्य आम्दानी गर्न सफल भएका छन् ।
            परम्परागत शैलीको अदुवाखेतीबाट आधुनिकीकरण हुन थालेपछि उत्पादन र आम्दानीमा वृद्धि भएको किसानको भनाइ छ ।
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

PDF rendered from MPDF:
[image]