# Dompdf-Laravel Unicode character not rendering correctly

Tags: php, html, laravel, utf-8, dompdf

I am using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) to load PDF's in my laravel application. I need to load custom **unicode fonts(sinhala)** in to the pdf. To do this, I downloaded my external fonts and copied the font folder and then it load to `storage/fonts` directory by [load_font.php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807562/13832493).
I have used css in my blade file as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Noto-2;
    font-display: block;
    src: url({{ asset('fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Light.ttf') }}) format("truetype");
}
body {
    font-family: Noto-2 !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px!important;
}
```

I also set meta tag UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

HTML part:

```
<td class="td_cus" rowspan="5">
   <span class="title">මික් ආහාර සේවය</span>
   <p class="company_address">
      2 වැනි මහළ,<br>
      <span style="font-family: helvetica !important;">M I C </span>සුපර් සෙන්ටර්,<br>
      මොරටුව,<br>
      ශ්‍රී ලංකාව.
   </p>
</td>
```

Laravel controller:

```
 $path = Storage::disk('local')->path("letters(".$letterCount."-letters).pdf");
 $pdf = PDF::loadview('templates.letterSinhala', ['details' => $details])
        ->setPaper('a4', 'portrait')
        ->save($path);
```

When I load my html page normally, the font works perfectly. However, when I am trying to load the font in the PDF, the font does not display correctly.  Could somebody please guide me on how to load the font correctly.

On a normal page(HTML view), it shows as follows:

[HTML view - correct text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zTko.jpg)

When I generate the PDF, it shows as follows:

[PDF view - incorrect text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhixm.jpg)

***NOTE:** Please see upper two images, that can be easy to understand the issue;*

The problem is sinhala text displaying incorrectly on PDF,  but when i **copy & paste** that somewhere , the text show in correctly.

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue? Please help..

Comment: compound letter are hard to render by these libraries, so if you try some other hard fonts they can lead to such errors, even trying with jspdf, or any other packages like mpdf, tcpdf etc try to load the html to images & put that image in pdf that is the only solution, there are other users as well asking the same questions

Comment: see these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951797/bangla-font-showing-mismatch-laravel-dompdf), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63324087/dompdf-problem-with-displaying-nepali-character/63418338) & [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010557/sinhala-font-not-support-in-laravel-barryvdh-laravel-dompdf-package#comment114934541_65010557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution for that with [Mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/), we changed library to **Mpdf**.  The **Mpdf** has much [Unicode fonts](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-7-x.html) and also include  [Sinhala Unicode font](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/available-fonts-v6.html) - ([Kaputaunicode](http://www.kaputa.com/slword/kaputaunicode.htm)).

In sinhala case you can use only **Kaputaunicode** font, because [other sinhala unicode fonts](https://www.language.lk/en/download/unicode-fonts/) doesn't support with **Mpdf**,  other sinhala unicode fonts rendering same as **Dompdf**.

But fonts rendering not perfect, some complex combinations not rendering correctly.

1. [***Text diff. image***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbHoh.jpg)
2. [***Paragraph text***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ithk.jpg)

- you can get idea from this images

Anyway **Mpdf** text rendering is good than **Dompdf** in my case.

The CSS Styling different with comparing Dompdf.
And Mpdf rendering time less than Dompdf

In Controller :

```
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

$path = Storage::disk('local')->path("_letters(".$letterCount."-letters).pdf");
$view = View::make('templates.letterSinhala', ['details' => $details]);
$html = $view->render();
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'UTF-8', 'format' => 'A4-P', 'autoScriptToLang' => true, 'autoLangToFont' => true]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Better and more simple package for laravel is `vatttan/apdf` that will be install by

`composer require vatttan/apdf`

See This in [github](https://github.com/vatttanweb/APdf)